# Generic type for object values

Tags: typescript, generics

This question is aimed purely at typings

Let's say we have a simple generic function type:

```
type Fn<T> = (input: T) => boolean
```

What I'd like to do is create function which when parameterized with an object type, will take an object of the same shape as the generic argument (same keys), but the values will be of type `Fn` with the fields type as generic argument.

With an example:

```
type Val = {
  a: string
  b: number
}
```

And when given as a generic argument to my function `f` this type `Val` I'd like it to take an object like this:

```
f<Val>({
  a: (input: string) => true, // Fn<string>
  b: (input: number) => false, // Fn<number>
  c: (input: boolean) => false // Compiler error
  // a: (input: number) => false -> would also be compile error
})
```

How would I type the function's argument here? Is this possible in ts?:

```
function f<T>(input: ???): void {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you need is

```
function f<T>(input: {[P in keyof T]: Fn<T[P]>}): void {
```